# Why is the answer for the following expression $\cot\theta\sin\theta$, not $\tan\theta\sin\theta$?

Tags: trigonometry

Why is the answer for the following expression $\cot\theta\sin\theta$, not $\tan\theta\sin\theta$?

> $\dfrac{1}{\cos\theta}-\cos\theta$ is equal to which of the following?
>   \begin{alignat*}{2}
> & (1) \tan\theta\sin\theta\quad? \hspace{8em} && (3) \cos\theta\cot\theta \\
> & (2) \cot\theta\sin\theta\quad\checkmark \hspace{8em} && (4) \sec\theta\sin\theta
> \end{alignat*}

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Because the book (or who wrote the checkmark) made a mistake, apparently.

Comment: Please [do not use pictures](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.

Answer (score 2):

we have $$\frac{1}{\cos(x)}-\cos(x)=\frac{1-\cos^2(x)}{\cos(x)}=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos(x)}=\tan(x)\sin(x)$$
since $$\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\cdot \sin(x)=\tan(x)\sin(x)$$
better?

Comment: Why.......................

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is $\tan\theta\sin\theta$. Who wrote the checkmark was wrong.

Indeed, for $\theta=\pi/3$ we have
$$
\cot\theta\sin\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
but
$$
\frac{1}{\cos\theta}-\cos\theta=2-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}
$$
By the way, $\cot\theta\sin\theta=\cos\theta$, so the equality
$$
\frac{1}{\cos\theta}-\cos\theta=\cot\theta\sin\theta
$$
only holds for $\cos^2\theta=1/2$, that is, for
$$
\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}+k\frac{\pi}{2} \qquad \text{$k$ any integer}
$$